# From parametrization to diffeomorphism

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f_1\in C^1(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f_2\in C^1(V,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be two maps from open connected subsets $U$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ (with $1\leq k \leq n$), such that

- $f_1$ and $f_2$ are injective immersions
- $f_2$ and $f_2$ are homeomorphism onto the same domain $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

Does this imply that $f_1^{-1}\circ f_2$ is a diffeomorphism from $V$ to $U$ ?

To prove this, I tried to check if the Jacobian of $f_1^{-1}\circ f_2$ is invertible, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Can't you show that each $f_i$ is an embedding, hence a diffeomorphism onto its image?

Comment: What I think I am having trouble with, is the notion of being a diffeomorphism from an open set onto a domain $D$ that is not an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, how to make sense of the fact that $f_i^{-1}$ is smooth on $D$.

Comment: It's not an open set, but it is a submanifold.

Comment: I am guessing the idea is to say that $D$ is a manifold, but the whole idea here is to check this result in an elementary way, with no prior knowledge of the notion of an abstract manifold